# Argument Out Of Range Exception, what to do

Tags: arrays, list, range

I'm trying to make hacker game, I have own cmd, where I typing commnads, but I'm getting this problem and I don't know what I'm doing bad.

This is the first code in Program.cs

```
if (enter == "del" + space + FIles.files1[0] && admin == true && connected == true && cdMain == true )
            {
                FIles.files1.RemoveAt(0);

                Console.WriteLine("");
                FIles.files1.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine(successfull);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            }
            if (enter == "del" + space + FIles.files1[1] && admin == true && connected == true && cdMain == true)
            {
                FIles.files1.RemoveAt(1);

                Console.WriteLine("");
                FIles.files1.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine(successfull);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            }
if (enter == "del" + space + FIles.files1[2] && admin == true && connected == true && cdMain == true)
            {
                FIles.files1.RemoveAt(2);

                Console.WriteLine("");
                FIles.files1.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
               // FIles.files1.AddRange(1);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine(successfull);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            }
            if (enter == "del" + space + FIles.files1[3] && admin == true && connected == true && cdMain == true )
            {
                FIles.files1.RemoveAt(3);

                Console.WriteLine("");
                FIles.files1.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine(successfull);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            }
```

and here is a second with List

```
class FIles
{
    public static List<string> files1 = new List<string>();

    public static void Files1()
    {
        files1.Add("file1.exe");
        files1.Add("file2.exe");
        files1.Add("file3.exe");
        files1.Add("file4.exe");
        files1.Add("file5.exe");
    }

}
```

Error arrive when I try to delete the thirth, please help.

Comment: Do you call FIles.Files1() to initialize the list? May I add your naming is pretty confusing... I thought you had a static constructor at first.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling Files.Files1() to initialize list. When I type del file1.exe, it works fine,second too, but if I want del file3.exe it say error array out of range

Comment: Try simply iterating over all the elements of files with a for loop printing out the current index each time and see at which point it crashes. Better yet, put a breakpoint in `FIles.Files1()` to ensure it is really called.

Comment: I wrote this and I didn't get any error                                                          if (enter == "del")
                {
                    foreach (var fls in FIles.files1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(fls);
                    }

                }

Comment: The I wrote this    Console.WriteLine(FIles.files1.IndexOf("file1.exe"));
                    Console.WriteLine(FIles.files1.IndexOf("file2.exe"));
                    Console.WriteLine(FIles.files1.IndexOf("file3.exe"));
                    Console.WriteLine(FIles.files1.IndexOf("file4.exe"));
                    Console.WriteLine(FIles.files1.IndexOf("file5.exe"));                                          and no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ExampleList.Count; i++)
{
    if (enter == "del" + space + FIles.files1[i] && admin == true && connected == true && cdMain == true )
    {
            FIles.files1.RemoveAt(i);

            Console.WriteLine("");
            FIles.files1.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine(successfull);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
     }
}
```

The problem with your code is that the size of your list is changing each time you call `RemoveAt`. After two calls your list has a size of 3 and  `FIles.files1[3]` is out of range.

Comment: Oh man you are fkin best, thank you man, now I know I must learn more, more and more thank you very much, I love you, I'm stupid :(

Comment: Oh, thank you, I give this information to my mind, very helpfull BIG thanks :), now I'm understand what was wrong with this :)